# Haml unordered list not rendering when "Save" button is clicked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Please forgive me. I am definitely a beginner at Haml and Ruby on Rails. Anyway, I have a web application, where at the top of the page, I am keeping track of the various elements on the page. The code that renders this page is as follows:

```
  - if @item_collection.is_a?(Feature)
    = render 'edit_fields', :f => f
  - else
    = render 'fields', :f => f
```

For my page, the else clause would be executed. The code behind my page is:

```
.field.large
  = f.label      :name, nil, 'data-help-id' => 'page_name'
  = f.text_field :name, disabled_if_unauthorized(@item_collection, :maxlength => 255, :title => "Edit Page")
  = f.error_message_on(:name, :css_class => 'error_message')
.field
  = f.label      :path, nil, 'data-help-id' => 'page_path'
  = f.text_field :path, disabled_if_unauthorized(@item_collection, { :maxlength => 255, :class => 'extra_margin', :title => "Edit Page" })
  = f.error_message_on(:path, :css_class => 'error_message')
.field.info
  = f.label      'Info'
  %ul.elements_count
    %li.elements_in_use{ :id => 'elements_in_use'}
    %li.unused_elements{ :id => 'unused_elements'}
    %li.undefined_elements{ :id => 'undefined_elements'}
```

When the "Save" button is clicked, the unordered list (elements_count) disappears. I know it's because I don't have "f." in front of those elements. The thing is, and again, forgive me because I'm just a beginner, putting "f." in front of the list elements won't work because %ul and %li are not Rails field helpers. Does anyone know what I can do to get these list elements to quit disappearing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct in that you don't need 'f' in front of non rails form helpers.

Tried a similar setup to yours and I see the unordered list show up (with no content), do you see the list if you view source? Maybe a CSS file is hiding the bullets?

Comment: Yes, that is what I see too: in Firefox, if I inspect the elements (using FireBug), I can see the unordered list element. The listed items are there too, but they're grayed out and do not have values. Do you know how I could find out if the .css file is hiding the items? I've looked through the .css file and have not been able to spot anything that would say the listed items are to be hidden. Thanks!

Comment: `list-style-type: none;` will hide bullets in CSS so try searching for that.

Comment: Thanks, KreeK! The list-style-type was indeed set to none. I changed it to "disc," which is the default for unordered lists. However, only the bullet point shows up, with no data behind it. I'm guessing that when I click "Save," the data does not get refreshed or rendered.

Comment: You're welcome, I gets bugs like this sometimes too, if you know it should work but something weird is going on, something weird is probably going on :)